# Can the rear window on a vinyl Miata top be reattached?

Tags: interior, window, miata, soft-top

Six years ago I had a local company replace the worn top on my 2000 Mazda Miata with a new Robbins vinyl one. Today the window completely detached from the top, and a frame separated from the glass. Everything fell down onto the rear deck and the only thing connecting the window to the car is the defroster wire. There's some squishy little black bits scattered around, so I'm guessing the southern US climate defeated whatever adhesive they used. The warranty on the top is five years, and the installers don't appear to be in business anymore.

The top is otherwise in good shape. Is it possible to reattach the frame and window to the top and keep the rain out?

Comment: You can always try duct tape ... J/K! Quite a conundrum. I'd suspect if the top itself is in good shape, with no tears or problems with it being warped or out of shape, a quality body shop should be able to reaffix the window into its home. That is supposition on my part, though. You could always ask them.